# Optimization behavior with && and &

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, optimization, logical-operators

Consider

```
 bool Fun1()
{
 ...
}
bool Fun2()
{
}
```

And somewhere in the main code I can have

```
if(Fun1() && Fun2()) //option-1
{
}
```

or

```
if(Fun1() & Fun2()) //option-2 
{
}
```

It seems with VS2012, with `option-1` it is not ensured that both functions are always executed while that happens on `option-2`. Specifically if one of the function returns `false` then other function is not executed with `option-1`. However the overall code requires both of them evaluated for proper behavior, which I am able to achieve with `option-2`. I would like to know if this behavior of `option-2` can change from compiler to compiler (also with optimization levels) or ensured by the standard?

Comment: I think I can put it this way: Since `&&` And Comparison Operator requires both sides to be true, then if first side is false it does not need to evaluate the second side. While `&` Bit-wise And, needs both sides to be evaluated before it gets applied.

Comment: Behaviour of option2 will not change, but there are some quirks. Mostly how is bool defined in toolset. Nonetheless `&` will always evaluate both results.

Comment: @Tomasz Plaskota Thats what I am worried about. Is it possible for the optimizer to understand the returs of the function are `bool` hence not technically required to evaluate both if one of them becomes false

Comment: It absolutely could, but I do not believe I've seen this in practice. If this is critical functionality I'd rather recommend calling those functions and saving results and only after that comparing results.

Comment: I would not use & for logical operations, you can get unexpected results when you use it with a function that returns `int`. You better call them explicitly, store results in vars and then do if on them.

Comment: @user6386155 it is more possible somebody (including yourself) will look into code, think that using `&` instead of `&&` is a mistake and "fix" it. Do not do that. Also note - short circuit is not optimization behavior but the language rule. It means that right side of `&&` will not be evaluated no matter what optimization level is set.

Comment: One readable alternative is `bool result1 = Fun1(); bool result2 = Fun2(); if (result1 && result2) ...`

Answer (score 5):

Standard explicitly says that for built-in types like `bool` operators `&&` and `||` are short-circuited - i.e, the first argument is evaluated first, and than second argument is evaluated only if first argument doesn't give a definitive answer to the statement - i.e. it  is `false` for `||`,  or `true` for `&&`.

Bit-wise `&` is following normal function call rules, so both arguments are evaluated, however, in the unspecified order.

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise-`&` will always evaluate both operands indeed. The compiler cannot optimize it away due to the *as-if* rule. But it is a *code smell* to program like that. Think about people who will maintain your code. Why is there one `&` instead of two? Is it a typo? etc.

I would *at least* pull the evaluation out of the if-statement.

```
  bool fun12 = Fun1() & Fun2();
  if (fun12) {
    . . .
```

In addition, you can't extend this approach to non-`bool` functions. You'll have to compare against `0` first.

And finally, `&&` evaluates the first operand and *then* (optionally) the second. The order of evaluation in `&` is unspecified (i.e. random).

Answer (score 1):

&& has short circuit behavior, in other words if the first operand is false, the second is not evaluated.  & doesn't have this behavior, so the second always is evaluated for sure.  However, if you are handling booleans, always use && not &, because & is used for bitwise operations.  For your problem, use this code:

```
bool a = Fun1();
if(Fun2() && a){
    //Fun2 must be the left operand
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run both the function the you can go with option-2 but It's not necessary to call both function you can go with option-1.

**Behavior** 
The behavior of option-1 and option-2 is not compiler dependent.

**Performance** The performance of option-1 is better than option-2

Answer (score 0):

This is not a matter of optimization but a matter of semantics.

&& follows the short-circuit evaluation rule and *mustn't* perform the second call  when the first returns false.

& follows ordinary evaluation and *must* perform both calls (unless it can prove that there is no side effect).

---

Anyway, one could think of a situation where for an && expression a compiler would enforce the evaluation of the two arguments in all cases (in the absence of a side effect), to exploit parallelism.